# Change grid based on current zoom in amCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

Let consider my question on a sample from amCharts site:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/area-with-time-based-data/

So, after page loading, chart is zoomed between 03:30 and 6:00 (based on X-axis values) and vertical grid step (difference between two vertical grid lines) is 0:30.

[image]

Now, I grab left slider at the top and move it right, so that minimal X value is 04:00. And there's still 0:30 step. It will switch to 0:10 at ~04:05.

[image]

My question is - how can I manually "speed up" this process of zooming? I mean, I'd like to switch to more narrow grid at 03:45 for example.

There's a possibility to attach a listener to zoom event and calculate time difference in current zoomed area, but I wasn't able to make vertical grid more narrow.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`minHorizontalGap`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minHorizontalGap) property.
The chart will try to size the grid accordingly to this value. If you decrease it (default value is `75`), the grid will be tighter in general.

I hope this fits your needs. Heres a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yaL6r94b/).

Comment: Terrific, thanks! Having some additional related question now, maybe you could help with that as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958446/amcharts-candle-stick-minimal-grid-step